# Inserting limited data into database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database

How can I put from how much to how much data to enter into my mysql database, api limits me to 1000 per day. So I would like if I enter 1000 for one session so that I can continue from 1000 and up and so on until I enter everything

```
mysql=mysql.connector.connect(
    host = host_input, 
    user = user_input, 
    passwd = passwd_input,
    database = database_input

)

with open('sadrzaj.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
   
    for p in data['filmovi']:
        
            naslov = p['naslov']
            iframe = p['iframe']
            opis = p['opis']

            movie = GetMovie(title=naslov, api_key='5f8abea5', plot='full')
            info = movie.get_data('Title', 'imdbRating', 'Genre', 'Year', 'Runtime', 'Country', 'Plot', 'Poster', 'Type', 'Language') 

            imdbRating = info["imdbRating"]
            genre = info["Genre"]
            year = info["Year"]
            runtime = info["Runtime"]
            country = info["Country"]
            poster = info["Poster"]
            typee = info['Type']
            language = info["Language"]

            mycursor = mysql.cursor()
                
            sql = "INSERT INTO serije_filmovi(naslov, iframe, opis, imdbRating, genre, years, runtime, country, poster, typee, language) values(%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            val = (naslov, iframe, opis, imdbRating, genre, year, runtime, country, poster, typee, language)
            print(naslov)
            mycursor.execute(sql,val)
            mysql.commit();
```

Comment: can't you simply count how many times you used `INSERT` - normal python code `count += 1`

Comment: you can also slice data to get only 1000 elements `data['filmovi'][:1000]` and next day `data['filmovi'][1000:2000]`, etc. You could keep this value in file and read it to varialbe `count` at start and use `data['filmovi'][count:count+1000]`. And save in file `count + 1000`